# Re-scaling automatic build from 2-cpu pizza-boxes to multi-cpu monster(s)?

Tags: java, build-automation, bamboo

Our current automated build consists of 1 master box and 4 core-2-duo pizza boxed (at around 2.5Ghz), with 3 GB memory each, all running Ubuntu Linux. (Using [bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/))

I have been asked to recalibrate this for running on one or more Solaris boxes. Our current build consists of a mix of java builds, long running integration test builds and automated Selenium tests - a fairly typical large project build. 
Our current environment has sufficient capacity, and we could probably lose a core or so without problem.

We are looking at 8 CPU Solaris machines with "large" amounts of memory (16-32GB? I can choose). Or maybe several 4 CPU machines ?

Can I expect behaviour to scale in a fairly linear manner within a single box? I am looking for actual experiences here; "theoretical" observations about how
IO may become a problem are not very interesting.

Comment: What are some of the stats of your current build process?

Comment: The selenium build uses 70-100% of both cores on the current system. The integration tests use little cpu, while the standard unit test build typically use most of a single core. Any other stats I can provide ?

Comment: i just added a bamboo tag since that is what you use, and it may be useful for searchers.

Comment: @Chii Fair enough, but I really think it applies to any of the java builds. We used quite a few different solutuions before landing on bamboo. I suppose bamboo is the only one that really supports clustering easily...

Comment: if you are worried about i/o time, you may wish to consider: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_0#RAID_0

Comment: @Ray Are you really sure about that ? I would actually think lots of separate small disks would perform better ? You have 4-5-6 processes that all want to trash the disk..? From what I've seen most raid0 solutions *increase* java compilation time.

Comment: I am totally jealous. Our current build "server" is about 3 years old and commonly takes about 2 hours to complete the whole build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I find that builds spend most of their time doing IO of some sort.  So increasing the number of CPUs doesn't help as much as you would think.
However, additional machines will have additional disks and network bandwidth. So they may help more. However, you can improve the configuration of a single box and possibly get the same performance.

How many builds you you typically have running at once?  If you typically have 2 builds queued now (and 2 running) then having four builds running at once is an improvement. But more than that isn't going to make much difference.

Eight core machines with 64 GB of memory are surprisingly standard for a new server these days.  In this configuration, I would suggest getting an SSD drive to improve disk access times and running four to eight builders/agents and that could be enough for if you typically have eight builds waiting at any time or less.

Comment: When the build is active, there's almost always 4 builds running (we currently have a maximum of 4 parallel builds - we figured the pizza boxes are only good for a single build at a time). There's usually a few in queue too. The selenium builds suck a fair bit more CPU than the average builds.

Comment: So any extra capacity we get we usually just eat up by adding another browser to the selenium tests ;) So there's actually an argument for a kick-ass 8 cpu box as well. With 64GB the agents could just run the whole build structure from ramdisk or similar. Thanx for a great response.

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are long running, you may benefit from having two builds, a quick build which runs all the fast tests, and a slower full build which might be only run over night.

Comment: We do that already. But there's good economy in running all the tests all of the time. *Everything* starts off the commit hook. We also have some nightly stuff...